# Calling a stored procedure expects @Id. Specified it every way possible

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

From the aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="ID.aspx.cs" Inherits="_ID" %>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxChildID"  runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Return" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

From the aspx.cs code-behind:

```
public partial class _ID : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con;

    // Here we declare the parameter which we have to use in our application
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxChildID.Text = Request.QueryString["id"];
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     con = new SqlConnection("server=(local); database=asdf;uid=asdf;pwd=asdfasdfasdfasdf");

     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.BigInt);
     cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = TextBoxChildID.Text;

     cmd = new SqlCommand("WebCallID", con);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
}
```

And the nasty debug page

> Server Error in '/' Application. Procedure or function 'WebCallID'
>   expects parameter '@Id', which was not supplied. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or
>   function 'WebCallID' expects parameter '@Id', which was not supplied.

Comment: You first need to add the parameters after `cmd = new SqlCommand("WebCallID", con);` where you create your `SqlCommand` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **define and add** the parameter **after** creating the `SqlCommand` - otherwise you wipe out anything you've already set...

```
// here, you're adding the parameter to "cmd" .... which exists from before
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.BigInt);
cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = TextBoxChildID.Text;

// and here you're creating a **NEW** "cmd" and thus WIPING OUT all work done before!
cmd = new SqlCommand("WebCallID", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

You need to write your code in **this order**:

```
// Create the command, define a stored procedure
cmd = new SqlCommand("WebCallID", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// **THEN** add the parameter - and don't call another "new SqlCommand()" again after this!!
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.BigInt);
cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = TextBoxChildID.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I missed that.